# I am getting this E/flutter (25055) error when I am running my App (Flutter , FireBase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

**I am getting this E/flutter (25055) error when I am running my App (Flutter, fireBase**

I tried Updating my flutter but still, I am getting the same logs
and these logs are making my App unstable and the App is crashing a lot

```
E/flutter (25055): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
E/flutter (25055): #0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (25055): #1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:104:41)
E/flutter (25055): #2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:120:26)
E/flutter (25055): #3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92:48)
E/flutter (25055): #4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96:40)
E/flutter (25055): #5      _MyHomePageState.getLists (package:form_app/pages/home.dart:518:30)
E/flutter (25055): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25055): #6      _MyHomePageState._getUnitNamesData (package:form_app/pages/home.dart:495:33)
E/flutter (25055): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25055):
```

my Flutter doctor

C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\src\flutter
• Framework revision f4abaa0735 (7 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
• Engine revision 241c87ad80
• Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
• Android SDK at C:/Users/afran/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
• ANDROID_HOME = C:/Users/afran/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.2)
• IntelliJ at F:\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
• VS Code at C:\Users\afran\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[√] Connected device (2 available)
• Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
• Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.131

• No issues found!

My App dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.0.0
  geolocator: ^7.0.1
  #geolocation: ^1.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0
  firebase_storage: ^10.0.1
  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  provider: ^5.0.0
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.4
  connectivity: ^3.0.2
  mailer: ^5.0.1
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.4
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says the problem:

```
Unhandled Exception: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform
```

Also you have the call methods:

```
E/flutter (25055): #0      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findKeyValueInMap (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (25055): #1      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get._findComponent (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:104:41)
E/flutter (25055): #2      DocumentSnapshotPlatform.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:120:26)
E/flutter (25055): #3      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:92:48)
E/flutter (25055): #4      _JsonDocumentSnapshot.[] (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_snapshot.dart:96:40)
E/flutter (25055): #5      _MyHomePageState.getLists (package:form_app/pages/home.dart:518:30)
E/flutter (25055): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25055): #6      _MyHomePageState._getUnitNamesData (package:form_app/pages/home.dart:495:33)
E/flutter (25055): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (25055):
```

You have to check at these rows what happens. We can't debug this because we don't have the code. You ask for a field that is not existing so it throws this exception.